# Filtering on unicode column names

Tags: python, sql-server, unicode, sqlalchemy

I would like to query a mssql database with the column name `u'F\u0151biztos\xedt\xf3'` using sqlalchemy (I'm using the pymssql driver). I've mapped this column name to an ascii column key, called `'Fobiztosito'`.

Now my table's column shows up as

```
In [32]: Biztosito.__table__.c.Fobiztosito
Out[32]: Column('F\u0151biztos\xedt\xf3', VARCHAR(length=50, collation=u'Hungarian_Technical_CI_AS'), table=<BIZTOSIT>, key='Fobiztosito')
```

Filtering on this column fails though (full stack trace here: http://pastebin.com/G20T6s92):

```
In [38]: session.query(Biztosito.pk).filter(Biztosito.Fobiztosito=='AHB').all()
<type 'str'>: (<type 'exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError'>, UnicodeEncodeError('ascii', u'params dictionary did not contain value for placeholder: F\u0151biztos\xedt\xf3_1', 58, 59, 'ordinal not in range(128)'))
```

This is the query statement

```
In [37]: print session.query(Biztosito.pk).filter(Biztosito.Fobiztosito=='AHB').statement
SELECT [BIZTOSIT].[BiztKod]
FROM [BIZTOSIT]
WHERE [BIZTOSIT].[F\u0151biztos\xedt\xf3] = %(F\u0151biztos\xedt\xf3_1)s
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Would guess that there is a bug in SQLA and it uses the original column name for placeholder, but ascii for the placeholder dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use utf-8 collation? I am working with Russian language, everywhere i'm using only utf-8, Unicode or UnicodeText when i need to work with unicode text or symbols or querying tables.

```
cat_name = self.category.query.with_entities(models.Category.category_name,models.Category.id).\
       filter_by(category_name=u'Категория 1').first()
```

Comment: as you can see my problem is not in the query argument (in your case category_name), but in the column naming. The same error happens with integer values as well, as shown here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/YbeijtyvpdU

Comment: Then why just rename all columns? :D